# Show/hide table row if a child DIV is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a table with multiple entries. After each entry table row is an edit table row, with a column spanned cell, inside of which is a DIV which HTML is dynamically loaded into. The problem is that having all these empty table rows causes a lot of extra whitespace to appear on the page when it's rendered.

I understand I can't dynamically load HTML directly into the cell, so I have a DIV in it which I load the content into.

I want to hide any table row while the child DIV in it is empty, and show that table row once information has been dynamically loaded into the child DIV. This dynamically loaded information can also removed so I need it to be hidden again once it's empty again.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td colspan="3"><div></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



$("tr").each(function() {
    if (this.children().filter(":empty").length) {
        this.hide();
    } else {
        this.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's your javascript code?

Comment: I've added it just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `div` isn't a child, it's a grandchild, thus `children()` won't find the `div`s. Use the context or `find` instead.
- You are operating `hide` and `show` on the DOM element, not the jQuery element. You need to wrap it in jQuery first.

Therefore, [run this code everytime you load something](http://jsfiddle.net/rtgSG/2/):

```
//find empty divs and hide it's tr
$("div:empty").closest('tr').hide();

//find non-empty divs and show it's tr
$("div:not(:empty)").closest('tr').show();
```

And look ma! No loops! No `each`! :D

Comment: Check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/satysalokhe/rtgSG/1/) illustrating Joseph jQuery code

Comment: Thanks but does this only run once? When I dynamically load into the DIV it remains hidden.

Comment: @SatishJS updated my code and I now use a different solution.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly when detecting the empty divs, but when after i've dynamically loaded content into the div  `$("div:not(:empty)").closest('tr').show();` won't trigger as it still thinks the div is empty?

Comment: @cianz It's not a "live script", unless you use a timer to run it on intervals or run it after every append of content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Reason being: `$(this)` is a JQuery object, which allows you to call JQuery methods like `.children()` and `.filter(":empty")` on it, whereas `this` is only a Javascript object...